# R <- How to use data.table's fread and fwrite when data contains newlines?

Tags: r, csv, data.table, fwrite, fread

I have problems when having to save a data.table object to a file with text columns that can contain new lines or other types of characters.

For example:

```
x <- data.frame( 
       x = c(1,2,3), 
       y = c("Lorem ipsum dixit", 'the "brown"\nfox', "a|b"),  
       stringsAsFactors = F)
```

I write it to file with:

```
data.table::fwrite(
     dataset,
     "testfile.tsv",
     sep = "\t",
     na = "NULL",
     quote = TRUE,
     eol = "\n",
     append = FALSE,
     col.names = !append,
     row.names = FALSE,
     qmethod = "escape"
)
```

The output seems OK to me:

```
"x" "y"
1   "Lorem ipsum dixit"
2   "the \"brown\"
fox"
3   "a|b"
```

However when I read the dataset from file with

```
data.table::fread("testfile.tsv")
```

I get error:

```
Error in data.table::fread("x.gitignore.tsv") : 
Expected sep (' ') but new line, 
  EOF (or other non printing character) ends field 0 
  when detecting types from point 0: fox"
```

I have tried to explicitly read stating the quoting character with:

```
data.table::fread("testfile.tsv", 
  sep "\t", header = T, na.strings = "NULL", quote = "\"")
```

but I still get the same error.

I also tried to use read.delim but it skips the first row of data for some reason:

```
read.delim("testfile.tsv", header = T, sep = "\t", na.strings = "NULL")
```

So how can I write and read back such data frames using data.table and fwrite?

Comment: You shouldn't use "\t" as a separator. Use instead ";" it would give far less errros.

Comment: If you need to save/restore data.table object with the benefice of good performances (which is basically what `fread` and `fwrite` bring), I recommend to have a look at either feather format or - specifically for R, impressive `fst` package. With `fst`, sole drawback is that you wont be able to exploit data in other environments but if you stick to R you won't find better

Comment: @Emmanuel-Lin: definitively don't agree: pretty more probable to have ";" in text data than tabulations + this should have nothing to do with this issue of newlines "\n"

Comment: @EricLecoutre I guess it is a believe, I often had some issues with tabs. But yeah, the issue here is with "\n", saving object as a rdata file might help

Comment: rda objects are "pure R" and writing/reading performance are not good. Have a look at `fst` package: you will be impressed! I achieved performance of 450Mb/s writing on SSD! (and I have nothing to do with package: not author or whatever).

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. Just to be clear, I can't change the format it has to be a tsv file and the text field can contain new lines etc

Comment: ...I don't originate the source files :) and I have to exchange them in the format required.. but I'll try feather for sure :)

Comment: Consider posting this on the data.table bug tracker.